# How to setup organization wise IDP Login with Keycloak Phase Two

Tags: angular, keycloak, identity-provider

For an organization-based identity provider authentication, I was trying to integrate PhaseTwo(https://github.com/p2-inc/) in my demo project.

I wanted to use the keycloak implementation for two different organization (different website). When I am redirecting from one site, I need to show IDP assigned (GitHub) to that organization (organiation2).
[image]

When I am redirecting from other site, I need to show the IDP assigned (google) to that organization (organiation1).

[image]

I saw `idpHint` can use to select a particular identity provider. But i don't want to specify IDP. I want to select based on organization. If there is a keycloak settings in JS or Angular library, it would be helpful.

Anyone can help with this? Thanks in advance.